# Difference between the types pid_t vs tid_t?

Tags: linux, ptrace

Are these supposed to be different types on Linux?
I noticed that I was able to pass a `pid_t` object to a function requiring `tid_t` param and did not get an error.

If they are used interchangeably, why were there separate types?

(I get that "pid" should stand for "process-id" whereas "tid" for "thread-id")

Comment: You should never assume that they are interchangeable. One goal of abstractions is to hide implementation details. The implementation details may change at any time and thus you must not do anything that assumes today's implementation (of course there are always exceptions to the rule).

Comment: Both are `typedef`d to some integer type, which is why the compiler can't catch you interchanging them. It doesn't mean you are allowed to.